# Is Google Clouds Compute Engine VM instance a good fit to run a selenium project?

Tags: python, selenium, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

after building a Selenium(Python) project (running on chrome with --headless flag) we'd like it to run on a cloud platform easily accessible from anywhere. The key point would be executing and terminating the script from anywhere at any time. I know that google cloud offers VM instances under the Compute Engine section. **My question is**, would it be a **great fit for selenium or not**? I really like Google Cloud because of the prices, but yet don't know if there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Before deciding you should understand what type of feature your organization needs and how much you want to pay for them. Remember that the right cloud service provider helps you achieve your business goal by enhancing the functioning of your organization. If you opt to use Google Cloud services please refer to below points.

Google Cloud Platform supports Selenium as well as all types of testing [continuously](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/devops/devops-tech-test-automation) throughout the software delivery lifecycle.

Make a note that you'll have to run Selenium using a "Virtual Framebuffer" in order to have the display of your GCE instance.

Here's how you set a Virtual Framebuffer up in Ubuntu:

> sudo apt-get install xvfb

> sudo Xvfb :10 -ac

Then, before starting your selenium script, just run:

> export DISPLAY=:10

Here is an [example](https://dev.to/googlecloud/using-headless-chrome-with-cloud-run-3fdp) of how to use chrome with --headless flag + Selenium on Cloud Run.